# Is it legal to assign beneficial ownership of a property without transferring the title?

Tags: property, australia, trusts-and-estates, tax

Suppose an individual owns a house for investment purposes, and wants to assign the ownership of the house to a trust. To avoid the need for stamp duty and other complexities, could the owner just sign a contract with the trust that assigns all benefits associated with the ownership of the property to the trust?

Comment: This is really two distinct questions. One is whether you can declare yourself a trustee of property you own for the benefit of another (generally yes). The second is whether doing this actually avoids stamp duty and other complexities (I'll defer to someone more familiar with Australian law on that point).